# Bootstrap tabs plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I have downloaded [Bootstrap Tabcordion](https://github.com/aexmachina/tabcordion) plugin, that collapse tabs to accordion when mobile screen is loaded.
I can't make the plugin work. I followed the instructions but I am not sure how to call the functions.

My header.php file contains the link to bootstrap.min.js and I have pasted the Markup code in my wordpress admin page. As a result on my site, the content is there and some of the css too, but it doesn't make what the plugin should does.

How do I have to use the .ZIP file that I have gotten when I have downloaded the plugin? Do I have to unzip and drag and drop the plugin's files in the root of my site?

**My header.php file**

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Temporary Gallery, Centre for contemporary art, Köln" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap-responsive-tabs.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<head>
```

**My Wordpress admin page**

```html
<div class="tabcordion">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-target=".home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".messages">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".settings">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="home active in">
      <h3>Home</h3>
      <p>Rhoncus magna nec enim, et proin aliquet mid, porta magnis.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
      <h3>Profile</h3>
      <p>Odio mattis, non ut! Porttitor nunc phasellus cras elementum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="messages">
      <h3>Messages</h3>
      <p>Enim hac tristique elementum, nec rhoncus porttitor sagittis cum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="settings">
      <h4>Settings</h4>
      <p>Arcu auctor, porttitor tincidunt, aliquam ut ut, placerat porta pulvinar dictumst?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This javascript I don't know where to paste:**

```js
$('.tabcordion').tabcordion()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabcordion is not a function
    at index.html:41
```

You are missing the tabcordion.js file, where that function is defined.

Download the ZIP archive from the Bootstrap Tabcordion website, follow their installation procedure (that bower install command) and include the needed files in your HTML :

```
<head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Temporary Gallery, Centre for contemporary art, Köln" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/tabcordion/tabcordion.js"></script>
<head>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cuqtfqt/)

Comment: I don't understand the bower install command. Could you explain me how it is supposed to be proceeded?

Comment: bower is a package manager for your web developpement projects. Check it out : http://bower.io   You will need to install NPM too

Comment: You can probably make it work without using bower though. Download this script https://github.com/aexmachina/tabcordion/blob/master/tabcordion.js and include it in your HTML page.

Comment: Ok! I have copied and pasted this script in my HTML page. Now the result changed a bit, but still not working…

Comment: You are right, I think I am missing the tabcordion.js file. Do I have to implement the js file in the root of my site? I have this in my .php page where the function should be applied, it is probably wrong? `<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.tabcordion').tabcordion() 
</script>`

Comment: You have to download the file and include it in your page using the <script> tag. Just like you did with the boostrap and jquery scripts.

Comment: I think we misundertood something… This is my situation now: I am working on Worpress with my own theme. I have a file called header.php, in which java and jquery links are present. I have another .php file that I used as a template for one of my wordpress page. This page (from template) should get the bootstrap tabs I am trying to install. So, when I download the .ZIP file from GitHub, what should I do then? From what I just explained in the lines above, would be possible for you to explain me step by step how I have to proceed? It turns out as a nightmare, I got too confused…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153473/discussion-between-lolo-and-roger-cageot).

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the *href=""*

Please use the *href*

see the below code for your ref:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href=".home">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href=".menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href=".menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href=".menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
```

Comment: His HTML code is fine. It's actually a copy-paste from the Github page. Your answer is misleading .